# Drools: create a conditional rule to match an input as list for each condition with permutations and combinations

Tags: drools, business-process-management, drools-kie-server

In Drools how do I create a conditional rule to match if

1) input is a list.

2) each condition column will has its own list

3) *Condition should match in permutations and combinations of all condition lists*

If my decision table is in below format

```
------------------------------------------------
COND.  |  CONDITION  | CONDITION| ACTION
------------------------------------------------
Store |  ProjectCode | Country  | ArticleNumber  
------------------------------------------------
10    |   1001       |   USA    |   AD112
20    |   1002       |   UK     |   AD113
30    |   1003       |   USA    |   AD114
40    |   1004       |   SWE    |   AD112
50    |   1005       |   GER    |   AD114
```

I will have conditions in list form like below

```
ArticleRule{
List<String> stores = Arrays.asList("10","30","40","50");
List<String> projectCodes = Arrays.asList("1001","1002","1004","1005");
List<String> countries = Arrays.asList("USA","GER","UK");
}
```

My result by creating a permutation and combination of all list would be.
Output : (AD112,AD114)

In my real use case each list might have 1000 values in it.
And my decision table can have a million records.

How can I achieve using drools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have each row as a fact Article with fields `store`, `projectCode`, `country`, `articleNumber`. Your rule would be

```
rule select
when
  $article: Article(
      store in ("10","30","40","50"),
      projectCode in ("1001","1002","1004","1005"),
      country in ("USA","GER","UK") )
then
  System.out.println( $article.getArticleNumber );
end
```